# Listing of all gnome-terminal windows

Tags: linux, console, terminal, gnome

My ubuntu setup, has various shell-scripts that help me get my work done. Of which, many of the important ones, are persistent. I have a single shell, that does the "loading" of these various persistent shells.

However i would like it to be able to monitor all the various sub-shell. And to be able to recreate it, after it itself has closed / any sub-shell closes.

Making the whole thing fully automated.

Currently, each shell would have its own unique title : hence even a simple list of all opened gnome terminal titles would work... >.< problem is, getting that done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
$ wmctrl -l
```

to list all the windows managed by the window manager, or

```
$ wmctrl -l -x | grep gnome-terminal\\.Gnome-terminal
```

to list all the gnome-terminals.

Check `man wmctrl` for more info.

Answer (score 7):

To list the window titles of all `gnome-terminal` windows:

```
$ xdotool search --onlyvisible -class gnome-terminal getwindowname %@
```

The window title of each `gnome-terminal` window is the title of the current tab

The option `--onlyvisible` is not hiding minimized windows, or windows on other desktops. It suppresses "internal" windows, which are not really part of the GUI.

You can list the PIDs for the windows - note multiple or all terminal windows may belong to the same process of `gnome-terminal`:

```
$ xdotool search --onlyvisible -class gnome-terminal getwindowpid %@
```

To list the X window IDs, use the default action after search:

```
$ xdotool search --onlyvisible -class gnome-terminal
```

Comment: If in a gnome-terminal, I start another by `gnome-terminal &`  How can I get it's X window ID ?

Comment: @Philippe Interesting! Please ask that as a separate question! Best at https://askubuntu.com/ - It's the StackExchange for Ubuntu Linux